# Do I need a Microsoft account to use Windows Store?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

In Windows 8, I am using a local user account.  I don't have a Microsoft account at all.

Do I need a Microsoft account to use the Windows Store in Windows 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you need to register at the [Microsoft Store Online](http://www.microsoftstore.com/) to use it and for that you need a Windows Live login. If you click "sign in" at the top of the store you are redirected to [here](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1351257535&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=SAPI&wreply=https://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/SignIn?wlsid=913EE7F6944A47F99EABEA805F710A04&lc=1033&id=273461&mkt=en-US) and it requests explicitly in the page title "sign in to your Microsoft account"